# Optimise number of points scored with a fixed budget

Tags: optimization

Here is my problem:

- I have 50 pounds to spend
- There are 445 players available at various prices
- Each player has scored a random number of points

Is there a formula that will give me the the optimal combination of 11 players in terms of total points scored, where the amount I spend is less than or equal to £50?

I have been working on this programatically. My method would be to first select the top 11 point-scorers (which results in a total cost that is way over budget), and then iterate through to substitute the top scoring player that isn't in my team with the lowest scoring player that **is** in my team - so long as the incoming player is less expensive than the outgoing player - until my budget condition is met.

I'm unsure whether or not I need to focus on the points per pound value - wouldn't this lead me to the most *efficient* team, but not necessarily a team optimised for points scored?

Comment: This is call a "Knapsack Problem". You find an overview [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). A 200 page thesis with [Knapsack algoritms](http://www.diku.dk/users/pisinger/95-1.pdf).

Comment: Thanks very much. Now to solve.